# Translation of "Ja und wie" into English

Tags: translation, idiom

How can one translate "Ja und wie" into English as a good meaning?

in this context:
A fragt: Vermisst du Deutschland?
B antwortet: Ja und wie

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please specify in what context you want to translate this sentence and in particular what difficulties you are having that concern the German language (and not the English one)? Also, please state why general references such as dictionaries did not yield a satisfying result.

Comment: Hello Amiina & welcome. Hints for new users: 1. Please give as many details as possible, because we can only explain what we understand - and context is crucial. 2. Always describe your own efforts, even if you could *not* find a solution. People here are happy to *help*, but will not do the work for you. 3. This site is about the German language, simple questions of "please translate" are off-topic. We can help you *understand* what a German phrase means, then you can translate it yourself. We will also comment on translations you suggest. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This question is closed, but I wanted to mention that this particular idiom also exists in english with approximately the same meaning. "Yes, and how!"  or somewhat more commonly just "and how!" can be used to indicate enthusiastic agreement.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned there is not much context! So I guess you are looking to translate something like this:

> Gefällt es Dir? – Ja, und wie!

Here, “Ja und wie” points out that you are really positive and thus could be translated as “Yes, indeed!” or “Absolutely!” or “You have no idea how much I like it!”.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as:

> - Yes, indeed!
> - Yes, totally!
> - Absolutely yes!
> - Totally yes!

Comment: Can you state which context or meaning your suggestions are based on?

Comment: I personally would use these ones, when trying to express "Ja und wie", basically in any context I can now think of. I think there is not such a big difference in emphasis anyways.

Comment: My former statement was obsolete as I missed the OP giving some context, however in general (and when you posted your answer), the following applies: It’s difficult to be certain about all context a sentence like this could be used in (which is why we are so insistent on the asker to provide some context). For example, the if the sentence that the asker wanted to have translated had been “Ja, und wie?”, your translations would have been incorrect.